# combining multiple regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x, typeerror

I have a text file that contains the following lines

```
 ! R1    R(1,2)                1.0881        
 ! R2    R(1,3)                1.0881        
 ! R3    R(1,4)                1.0881      
 ! R4    R(1,5)                1.0881         
 ! A1    A(2,1,3)              109.4712         
 ! A2    A(2,1,4)              109.4712         
 ! A3    A(2,1,5)              109.4712         
 ! A4    A(3,1,4)              109.4712       
 ! A5    A(3,1,5)              109.4712         
 ! A6    A(4,1,5)              109.4712        
 ! D1    D(2,1,4,3)           -120.0           
 ! D2    D(2,1,5,3)            120.0            
 ! D3    D(2,1,5,4)           -120.0           
 ! D4    D(3,1,5,4)            120.0
```

To match everything, I am using two different Regular expressions.

```
RE1 = !\s\w(\d)\s+R\((\d),(\d+)\)\s+(\d\.\d+

RE2 = !\s\w(\d)\s+\w\((\d)+,\d,\d\)?,?\d?\s?\)\s+\d?\-?\d\d\d?.\d?\d?\d?\d?
```

How do I go about combining these two REs so that the code checks for one of the REs. Based one some of posts on SO, I have tried using '|' to concatnate the two expressions but all my attempts have resulted in a `typeerror` Here is one of my attempts:

```
 pattern = re.compile(re.compile(r'!\s\w(\d)\s+R\((\d),(\d+)\)\s+(\d\.\d+)') | re.compile(r'!\s\w(\d)\s+\w\((\d)+,\d,\d\)?,?\d?\s?\)\s+\d?\-?\d\d\d?.\d?\d?\d?\d?'))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Check the format (better use a parser), retrieve the values (split on the whitespaces). As it stands, your expression is complicated and error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get everything you need in a single regex

`([A-Z])(\d+)\s+\1\((\d+(?:,\d+)*)\)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)`

https://regex101.com/r/bJdcSc/1

```
 ( [A-Z] )                     # (1)
 ( \d+ )                       # (2)
 \s+ \1 \( 
 (                             # (3 start)
      \d+ 
      (?: , \d+ )*
 )                             # (3 end)
 \) \s+ 
 ( -? \d+ \. \d+ )             # (4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
!\s+[A-Z](\d)\s{2,}[A-Z]\((\d+),(\d+)?,?(\d+)?,?(\d+)?,?\)\s{2,}(-?\d+\.\d*)
```

might be close to what you like to write.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0gNsdE/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"!\s+[A-Z](\d)\s{2,}[A-Z]\((\d+),(\d+)?,?(\d+)?,?(\d+)?,?\)\s{2,}(-?\d+\.\d*)"
string = """
 ! R1    R(1,2)                1.0881        
 ! R2    R(1,3)                1.0881        
 ! R3    R(1,4)                1.0881      
 ! R4    R(1,5)                1.0881         
 ! A1    A(2,1,3)              109.4712         
 ! A2    A(2,1,4)              109.4712         
 ! A3    A(2,1,5)              109.4712         
 ! A4    A(3,1,4)              109.4712       
 ! A5    A(3,1,5)              109.4712         
 ! A6    A(4,1,5)              109.4712        
 ! D1    D(2,1,4,3)           -120.0           
 ! D2    D(2,1,5,3)            120.0            
 ! D3    D(2,1,5,4)           -120.0           
 ! D4    D(3,1,5,4)            120.0 
"""

print(re.findall(regex, string))
```

#### Output

> [('1', '1', '2', '', '', '1.0881'), ('2', '1', '3', '', '', '1.0881'),
>   ('3', '1', '4', '', '', '1.0881'), ('4', '1', '5', '', '', '1.0881'),
>   ('1', '2', '1', '3', '', '109.4712'), ('2', '2', '1', '4', '',
>   '109.4712'), ('3', '2', '1', '5', '', '109.4712'), ('4', '3', '1',
>   '4', '', '109.4712'), ('5', '3', '1', '5', '', '109.4712'), ('6', '4',
>   '1', '5', '', '109.4712'), ('1', '2', '1', '4', '3', '-120.0'), ('2',
>   '2', '1', '5', '3', '120.0'), ('3', '2', '1', '5', '4', '-120.0'),
>   ('4', '3', '1', '5', '4', '120.0')]

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OMPkUj/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/OMPkUj/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]